# MySQL COUNT with GROUP AND JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I need help to SELECT some information from 3 tables with one SQL query. I will try to explain it as much as possible.

I have the following 3 tables:

### Users

```
ID | FULL NAME | CATEGORY_ID
--------------------------
1  | JOHN DOE  | 3
2  | JOHN DOE  | 5
3  | JOHN DOE  | 2
4  | JOHN DOE  | 3
5  | JOHN DOE  | 3
```

### Categories

```
ID | NAME
----------------------
2  | CATEGORY NAME 1
3  | CATEGORY NAME 2
5  | CATEGORY NAME 3
```

### Registrations

```
ID | USER_ID
------------
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 4
```

Now I want the outcome of this SQL query to be an html table looking like:

**Category** | **Number Of Registrations**
CATEGORY NAME 2 | 3
CATEGORY NAME 3 | 3
CATEGORY NAME 1 | 1

So to sum it up, I have to select all `user_id` from `registrations` table, get the `category_id` for each user from `users` table and find the category `name` from `categories` table.

Is this doable?

Comment: Hi Epodax, I haven't try anything so far, I was wondering if it's even possible to have one SQL Query like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT c.name, count(r.user_id) 
FROM categories c 
inner join users u 
    on  u.category_id = c.id 
inner join registrations r 
    on r.user_id = u.id 
group by c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL tables form you're using doesn't feel right.

You should have a 'USERS' table as:

```
ID | FULL NAME

1 | JOHN DOE
2 | JOHN DOE
3 | JOHN DOE
4 | JOHN DOE
5 | JOHN DOE
```

'CATEGORIES' table as

```
ID | NAME

2 | CATEGORY NAME 1
3 | CATEGORY NAME 2
5 | CATEGORY NAME 3
```

'REGISTRATIONS' table as
(I believe this table will store what user has registered to what category)

```
USER_ID | CATEGORY_ID

1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 4
```

Then your query can be easily retrieved via:

```
SELECT c.name, count(*) as Number_of_Registrations
FROM categories c, registrations r 
WHERE c.id = r.category_id 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Am I wrong about the registrations table? Lemme know then, I'll provide a new solution accordingly.

Comment: Your solution is only necessary if a user can have multiple categories. If a user can only have one category, the original solution works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
select cat.`category name`, count(reg.user_id) from registrations reg
inner join users on reg.user_id = users.ID
inner join categories cat on cat.ID = users.category_id
group by cat.category_id
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick reply. I get the following error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'cat.category_name' in 'field list'

Comment: my mistake, I misnamed the name of the column, it's fixed now, though for future reference, you should try to avoid column names with spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$sql1="SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES";
$query1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
echo "<table>";
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
echo"<tr><td>". $row1['NAME']."</td >";
$sql12="SELECT COUNT(CATEGORY_ID) AS NumberOfUsers FROM USERS WHERE CATEGORY_ID='".$row1['CATEGORY_ID']."'";
        $query2=mysqli_query($con,$sql12);
        $row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
  echo"<td>".$row2['NumberOfUsers']."</td></tr>" ;
}
echo"</table>"
```